# Bootstrap columns not responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a responsive block in the middle of my page using Bootstrap.
But I cannot figure out why the columns dont respond to my bootstrap setup. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 mx-auto" style="background-color: blue; color: white;">
      test column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show your block css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I forgot to add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

to my html document. Now it works!

Answer (score -1):

In your example they are responsive... Bootstrap uses adaptive breakpoints.

If you want fluid, then you can use Foundation.